# What's the difference between gdalwarp and gdal_merge for mosaicing

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-merge

I wanted to merge around 20 dem tiffs each around 100MB, and I used gdalwarp (I know about virtual file option):

`gdalwarp $(list_of_tiffs) merged.tiff`

However this command took very long time, and after some 15min it was processing 5th image from set. I terminate it.

I then found that gdal_merge.py script can be used also for mosaicing, and tried it:

`gdal_merge.py $(list_of_tiffs)`

which completed in less then 3min.

As I expected that both commands would produce same result, I wonder what's the difference between the two, as to why gdalwarp takes so much time if result is same?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

While I don't know why GDAL provides this overlap in functionality, be sure to set the cache for gdalwarp to make it really fast:

```
# assuming 3G of cache here:
gdalwarp --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 3000 -wm 3000 $(list_of_tiffs) merged.tiff
```

Be sure to not define more cache than having RAM on the machine.

Comment: Had no idea about this tuning switch, which indeed speeds up the process. For reference 3000 is 3GB (more info http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/UserDocs/GdalWarp)  I have NumPy build with MKL in my system Python, but still `gdalwarp` must be doing something more, as NumPy can't be faster then C implementation, although can reach it.

Answer (score 15):

I just happened to come across this question and a potential answer when looking for something else.

> gdal_merge.py uses nearest neighbor resampling. If you want control
>   over the resampling used, you should use gdalwarp instead.

source: [trac.osgeo.org](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/UserDocs/GdalMerge)

Answer (score 7):

gdal_merge.py loads all files into memory before processing them. therefore it is not able to process large files if your memory is small. see [here](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-merge-MemoryError-td3775927.html)