# Merge tiffs into a single multi banded tiff

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp, gdal-merge

I have two geoTIFFS. The files cover the exact same area, both have 1 band(Block = 256x256) and both have a no data value of 0. They also have the same coordinate system.

I want to merge the files into a single tiff with two bands.

I tried this command:

```
gdal_merge.bat -n 0 -a_nodata 0 -separate -of GTiff -o merged.tif first.tif second.tif
```

But I kept getting a Memory error. After researching online, I then used the same command with the -createonly flag:

```
gdal_merge.bat -createonly -n 0 -a_nodata 0 -separate -of GTiff -o merged.tif first.tif second.tif
```

Followed By:

```
gdalwarp --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 500 -wm 500 merged.tiff mergedFINAL.tiff
```

However opening mergedFINAL.tiff in qgis just yields a blank screen. Can anyone see something Im doing wrong and offer me some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a blank image because you are not copying any data into the final output.  The creatonly flag does just that.  It creates a blank image of the right size (see the [documentation](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html)).  So your inputs in the warp operation should not be the blank output of the -creatonly operation (as that will obviously be blank as you discovered).

See [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44717/whats-the-difference-between-gdalwarp-and-gdal-merge-for-mosaicing) for an example of using gdal_warp for merging.  An alternative to this approach would be to make a VRT and then warp that.

gdal_merge loads the whole raster(s) into memory for speed whereas warp uses tiling to do the operation piecemeal (so less memory overhead).  A VRT is just a virtual raster - an xml representation of the result that you can 'solidify' into a real raster (if you need to) using translate or warp.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with `gdalbuildvrt` (using the `-separate` flag to treat inputs as separate bands instead of mosaicing them) and `gdal_translate`

In one line with no intermediate file (by writing to stdout and piping to stdin):

```
gdalbuildvrt -separate /vsistdout/ first.tif second.tif|gdal_translate /vsistdin/ merged.tif
```

If you don't want two copies of the data, you could always just write out the VRT, it's just a small text (XML) file that QGIS understands (and ArcGIS and anything else that uses GDAL under the hood).

```
gdalbuildvrt -separate merged.vrt first.tif second.tif
```