# Merge thousands of rasters with gdal_merge.py

Tags: gdal, merge

I have several thousands of small rasters, kb size, tens or hundreds of pixels most of them. Batch command of `gdal_merge.py` can't take all the files at once, so I am doing partial merges of chunks of 500 images, and that's relatively fast.

But when I try to merge the partial merges it takes way too much. In one even `gdal_merge.py` gave up and returned `Killed`.

Has anyone experienced something similar, and found an optimization?

Alternatives to `gdal_merge.py` are welcome

Comment: You can try to create a vrt file with `gdalbuildvrt` and `gdal_translate -of GTiff` on that VRT. I had faster results comparted to `gdal_merge` with huge files.

Comment: does it need to be with gdalbuildvrt or can be also done with gdal.Warp?

Comment: No, a `vrt` file derived from `gdal_merge.py -of VRT` is fine too as input.

Comment: Wow, I was not expecting such an improvement. I was a bit afraid because in the own documentation says that it might overwrite data with nodata, but it seems it worked. Do you want to write it as an answer so I accept it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create a vrt file with `gdalbuildvrt` or `gdal_merge.py -of VRT` and then run `gdal_translate -of GTiff` on that VRT.

Like this, I had much faster results compared to `gdal_merge` with huge files.

See [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/238403/87998) to a [similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44717/whats-the-difference-between-gdalwarp-and-gdal-merge-for-mosaicing/44739):

> gdal_merge.py loads all files into memory before processing them. therefore it is not able to process large files if your memory is small. see [here](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-merge-MemoryError-td3775927.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you manage to open all the rasters in QGIS 2.18 you can try QTiles plugin and merge them into the only one file with an extension *.mbtiles.

Comment: Right now i need the output as a tiff, or I should change some steps further, but I keep it as an option of other methods fail

Comment: When you open *.mbtiles layer in Qgis you can then save it as *.tif